# Write the dot product of $(1, 4, 5)$ and $(x, y, z) $as a matrix multiplication

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I'm very confused by this question in practice:

> Write the dot product of $(1, 4, 5)$ and $(x, y, z)$ as a matrix
> multiplication $Ax$. (The matrix A should only have one row). The
> solutions to $Ax = 0$ lie on a ___ perpendicular to the vector ___.
> The columns of $A$ are vectors in only __-dimensional space.

What I currently think is the dot product as a matrix multiplication $Ax$ is $Ax = \begin{bmatrix}1&4&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ where $A$ is $\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5\end{bmatrix}$. Hence the solutions to $Ax=0$ is the same as $x+4y+5z=0$. But what do those solutions lie on ___ perpendicular to what vector? Are the columns of A vectors in only 1-dimensional space?

---

**Answer:**

Thanks to @pipe's answer. The solutions to $x+4y+5z=0$ lie on a **plane** (because it's a three-variable equation) perpendicular to **$\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5\end{bmatrix}$**. Because for any solution $(x, y, z)$, its dot product with $\begin{bmatrix}1&4&5\end{bmatrix}$ is always zero. According to the formula, $cos\theta=\frac{\vec{a}\vec{b}}{||\vec{a}||||\vec{b}||}$, the numerator would be $0$, which makes $cos\theta=0$, therefore $\theta=90^\circ$. The columns of $A$ are vectors in only 1-dimensional space before there's only one entry in every column of $A$.

Comment: You've written the dot product as a matrix product correctly. The column vectors of length 3 form a three dimensional space. The ones you are interested in form the two dimensional subspace perpendicular to $[1,4,5]$.

Comment: In your question, $x$ is both a $3\times 1$ matrix and a number in such matrix?

Comment: @peterwhy I think so. I'm so confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions to $Ax=0$ lie on a *plane* perpendicular to the vector *$(1,4,5)$*.  The columns of $A$ are vectors in *$1$-dimensional* space.

Indeed,  $ax+by+cz=d$ is a plane perpendicular to $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: oh so is this "++= is a plane perpendicular to (,,)." something that is always true?

Comment: Yes.  It's easy to see that if you take two solutions,  $(x_0,y_0,z_0),(x_1,y_1,z_1)$, their difference dots $(a,b,c)$ to zero.

Comment: it's true for whatever d is?

Comment: Yes.  Changing $d$ gives a different plane with normal $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: just wondering if $A$ is a $2\times1$ vector, does $Ax$ lie on a line perpendicular to $A$?

Comment: Yes, I reckon if $A$ is $n×1$ then $Ax=0$ will be a *hyperplane* in $n$-space.  The equation reduces the dimension by $1$.

Comment: Actually $A$ would be $1×n$.  I get that mixed up too.